# GTA 4 PC - Can't login to Windows account for online play

Tags: games-for-windows-live

So when I run GTA 4 (I purchased with steam and run through steam) I can login with the social club thing thats just fine, but if I try to play the game online it asks for my windows account login details. When I put them in it says they are wrong but I've checked them by logging into the windows live website and to my emails, which is the same login details, but the game is still telling me my details are incorrect.

Is this a bug or is it broken or is there a fix?

Comment: Games For Windows Live accounts are not the same thing as your Windows User account that you log into your PC with - I doubt that the latter is going to work.

Comment: but i cant log into my windows live account on the account page but on the game it tells me the details are wrong

Comment: That's what games tend to say when servers are dead. I was unsure about GFWL in GTA IV, but with JonK confirming it I'd say the same. With GFWL dead I doubt you can still play online.